# Why isn't this template reactive?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

Why isn't this reactive?  And more importantly how can it be made reactive?

I'd like the data to be saved in Mongo and used in the template.  I could use a ReactiveVar or ReactiveDict.  Do I need two copies of the data?

Doesn't `Suspects.findOne('bruce')` return a reactive object already?  I tried putting the `human` answer directly on Bruce, but it didn't trigger an update.

The events fire, log(this) shows bruce's answer was changed, but the template doesn't re-render.  What's the good way to do this?

http://meteorpad.com/pad/KoH5Qu7Fg3osMQ79e/Classification

It's Meteor 1.2 with `iron:router` added:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<template name="question">
  {{#unless isAnswered 'human'}}   <!--  :-<  I'm not reacting here -->
    <div>Sir, are you classified as human?</div>
    <button id="no">No, I am a meat popsicle</button>
    <button id="smokeYou">Smoke you</button>
  {{else}}
    <div> Classified as human?  <b>{{answers.human}}</b></div>
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
// Why isn't this reactive?
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.question.helpers({
    isAnswered: function (question) {     // :-<  I'm not reactive
      var suspect = Template.instance().data;
      return (typeof suspect.answers[question] !== 'undefined');
    }
  });

  Template.question.events({
    'click #no': function () {
      this.answers.human = "No"; // :-<  I'm not reactive
      console.log(this);
    },
    'click #smokeYou': function() {
      this.answers.human = "Ouch";    // :-<  I'm not reactive
      console.log(this);
    }
  });
}

// Collection
Suspects = new Meteor.Collection('suspects');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Suspects.upsert('bruce', { quest: 'for some elements', answers: {}});
  });
  Meteor.publish('suspects', function() {
    return Suspects.find({});
  });
}

// Iron Router
Router.route('/', {
  template: 'question',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('suspects');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Suspects.findOne('bruce');
  }
});
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `events` are not actually updating the reactive data source (the db record). Instead of doing:

```
Template.question.events({
  'click #no': function () {
    this.answers.human = "No";
  }
});
```

The event needs to perform a database action, either through a direct `update` or through a `Meteor.call()` to a `Meteor.method`. For example:

```
'click #no': function(){
  Suspects.update('bruce', {'answers': {'human': 'no'}});
}
```

If you use this pattern, you will also need to set the correct `allow` and `deny` rules to permit the update from client code.  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow. Methods generally end up being a better pattern for bigger projects.

Also, I'm not sure off the top of my head that `Template.instance().data` in your `helper` is going to be reactive. I would use `Template.currentData()` instead just to be sure. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata

Comment: thanks!  fyi heres a [working meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/jfS9L85ikJpmDQYec/Classification%20(solved)).

Answer (score 1):

Very close you just need to use `ReactiveVar` by the sound of it it pretty much explains what it's :) http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar

and here's how to use it

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.question.onCreated(function () {
    this.human = new ReactiveVar();
  });

  Template.question.helpers({
    isAnswered: function (question) {
      return Template.instance().human.get();
    }
  });

  Template.question.events({
    'click #no': function (e, t) {
      t.human.set('No');
      console.log(t.human.get());
    },
    'click #smokeYou': function(e, t) {
      t.human.set('Ouch');
      console.log(t.human.get());
    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:** if you're using a cursor I usually like to keep it on the template level not on iron router:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.question.helpers({
    isAnswered: function (question) {
      return Suspects.findOne('bruce');
    }
  });

  Template.question.events({
    'click #no': function (e, t) {
      Suspects.update({_id: ''}, {$set: {human: 'No'}});
    },
    'click #smokeYou': function(e, t) {
      Suspects.update({_id: ''}, {$set: {human: 'Ouch'}});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I want the data to be left on Bruce and saved to Mongo.  Do I need to make two copies of the answer?  Also, thanks :-)

Comment: Also, doesn't `Suspects.findOne('bruce')` return a reactive object already?

Comment: @MichaelCole oh yeah I didn't see it missed it sorry.